# Highcharts area line is behind the vertical limit line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to do a graphic with highcharts and the problem is this:

[image: two muppets]
My line is behind the 100% line, the difference is small but my client can see it. Any help, please?

Edit:

My code

```
chart: {
  plotBackgroundColor: color = "#FFFFFF",
  spacing: [10, 10, 10, 10],
  style: {
    fontFamily: '"Flama-Book"', // default font
    fontSize: '13px'
  }
},
colors: colors_disp,
credits: {
  enabled: false
},
exporting: {
  enabled: false
},
legend: {
  enabled: false,
  layout: "horizontal",
  floating: false,
  itemHiddenStyle: null, 
  itemHoverStyle: null, 
  verticalAlign: "top"
},
navigation: {
  buttonOptions: {
    enabled: false
  }
scrollbar: {
  enabled: false
},
tooltip: {
  shared: true,
  useHTML: true,
  backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  borderColor: '#FFF',
  valueDecimals: 2  
 }
```

Comment: It would help if you showed code relating to that graph

Comment: Post updated, my friend.

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0m2bdc9j/ . This is related with fact that axis line limits plotarea, which apply clippath. To solve that you need to add space on yAxis (minPadding / maxPadding) or adapt ticks (min/max / tickPositioner)